# Bash: Remove lowest value from each line in a txt file and print

Tags: bash, awk

I've looked everywhere for help with it and cannot seem to get anything to work correctly. What I am attempting to do is take a .txt file with space delimited formatting, remove the lowest value, and print out the remaining values. Here is an example of what I'm talking about.

```
1234567890 Joe Blow 90 92 94
2345678901 Jane Kirk 91 58 72
```

and after running the code, I will get the following

```
1234567890 Joe Blow 92 94
2345678901 Jane Kirk 91 72
```

If possible, I would like to be able to use an awk statement as well. Thanks for any help with this in advance!

Comment: What if you have a user like this `2345678901 Paul Johan Doe 45 67 23`, with three names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (assuming your first three fields are not to be compared):

```
awk '{
  min = $4
  for(i = 4; i <= NF; i++) {
    min = (min < $i) ? min : $i
  }
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    printf "%s", ($i == min) ? "" : $i FS
  }
  print ""
}' file
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
1234567890 Joe Blow 90 92 94
2345678901 Jane Kirk 91 58 72
```

```
$ awk '{
  min = $4
  for(i = 4; i <= NF; i++) {
    min = (min < $i) ? min : $i
  }
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    printf "%s", ($i == min) ? "" : $i FS
  }
  print ""
}' file
1234567890 Joe Blow 92 94
2345678901 Jane Kirk 91 72
```